# Can't access Desktop Manager after upgrading to Kali Sana

Tags: kali-linux

After upgrading to Kali Sana I am not able to get the desktop manager. All I get is a white page displaying "A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please logout and try again."
Though I can access terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and run `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but they show nothing new to install or upgrade. 
`Who -r` shows run-level 2
And `gdm3` is on in run level 2

How can I get my DM back?

Comment: What happens if, at the Bash prompt, you enter `startx` or `Xorg` or `X`, or if you restart gdm manually?

Comment: Xorg- Fatal server error:
     (EE) server is already active for display 0. If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.

Comment: Gdm3- it shows nothing except the cursor keeps blinking after moving to next line.

Comment: startx- command not found.

Comment: X- shows the same error as xorg

Comment: [IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/9syps4.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Also when the terminal shows up there shows this line:
[57.112992] systemd-logind[2774]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@0.service

Comment: "ps -p 1 -o comm=" returns init and I think it should return systemd

Comment: Systemctl- Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1

Comment: Please don't add your reply as comments.  Instead, please [edit] your original post, add a big notice that says "EDIT:", and then add your reply to me.  Finally, please add a comment which pings me:  something like, "@unforgettableid:  see my edit to the question".  Each edit will bump your question to the top of the homepage and can get it more attention.

Comment: If gdm is broken through the update, you could try to replace it with lightdm. I know how to do that on Arch Linux, but not sure if it is the same. 1. Install lightdm. 2. `sudo systemctl disable gdm` 3. `sudo systemctl enable lightdm`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. When logout error appears, just press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>.
Enter your previously used root username abd password or create another user and after that, run this command

```
vi /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf        # use sudo for non root user
```

And change it

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=false
AutomaticLogin=root or user1 (if you create a new user and want to login from it)
```

To

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=true 
AutomaticLogin=root or user1
```